# The number of curves in the plane has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: real-analysis

Define a curve to be the image of a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R^2}$.   Let $X$ be the set of all curves.  Is $|X| = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Hint: (i) there are at least this many curves and (ii) a continuous function is determined by its values on a countable set (the rationals).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. Each continuous $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ is completely determined by its restriction to $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, which is a countable set. For each $x\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ there are at most $|\Bbb R^2|=2^\omega$ possible choices for $f(x)$, so there are at most $(2^\omega)^\omega=2^{\omega\cdot\omega}=2^\omega$ such functions. On the other hand, there are $2^\omega$ constant functions, so there must be exactly $2^\omega$ curves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A continuous function is determined by its action on the rationals, and there are only

$$\left|\mathbb{R}^2\right|^{|\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]|} = \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

functions from the rationals (in [0,1]) to the plane.  This gives us an upper bound.  And clearly there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ many such continuous functions, e.g. just take all the constant functions.